# 2D array Recursion

Tags: recursion, multidimensional-array

So I am trying to build a bubble breaker program.  The way the game works is that it has a board with several colors.  all spots coming off that spot (horizontal and vertical) not diaganol and off those you chech all around the new spot until no spots left

```
public void setSurroundingSimilarToTrue(int row, int col, int correctColor){
    if(row >= 0 && row < this.myBoard.length && col >= 0 && col < this.myBoard.length)
            if(this.myBoard[row][col].getColorValue() == correctColor){
                this.myBoard[row][col].setStatusTrue();
                //System.out.println(row);
                setSurroundingSimilarToTrue(row - 1, col, correctColor);
                setSurroundingSimilarToTrue(row + 1, col, correctColor);
                setSurroundingSimilarToTrue(row, col - 1, correctColor);
                setSurroundingSimilarToTrue(row, col + 1, correctColor);
            }           
}
```

This is what I did and I cant see whats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have infinite recursion with your code.
Before doing recursion, check if the current `row, col` position isn't already set to `True`.